# Extract specific words from text field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a table that contains a text field, there is around 3 to 4 sentences in the field depending on the row.

Now, I am making an auto-complete html object, and I would like to start typing the beginning of a word and that the database return words that start with those letters from the  database text field.

Example of a text field: I like fishsticks, fishhat are great too

in my auto-complete if I would type "fish" it would propose "fishsticks" and "fishhat"

Everything works but the query.

I can easily find the rows that contains a specific word but I can't extract only the word, not the full text.

```
select data_txt from mytable match(data_txt) against('fish', IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 10
```

I know it is dirty, but I cannot rearrange the database.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

Here's what I got, thanks to Brent Worden, it is not clean but it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SUBSTRING(data_txt, 
LOCATE('great', data_txt),
LOCATE(' ' , data_txt, LOCATE('great', data_txt)) - LOCATE('great', data_txt)
)
 FROM mytable WHERE data_txt LIKE '% great%'
LIMIT 10
```

any idea on how to avoid using the same `LOCATE` expression over and over?

Comment: Are you applying SQL full text search on your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LOCATE` to find the occurrence of the word.

Use `LOCATE` and the previous `LOCATE` return value to find the occurrence of the first space after the word.

USE `SUBSTR` and the previous 2 `LOCATE` return values to extract the whole word.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tagsql ="SELECT * from mytable";
$tagquery = mysql_query($tagsql);

$tags = array(); //Creates an empty array

while ($tagrow = mysql_fetch_array($tagquery)) {

   $tags[] = tagrow['tags']; //Fills the empty array

}
```

If the rows contain commas you could use -

```
 $comma_separated = implode(",", $tags);
```

you can replace the comma for spaces if they are separated as spaces in your table.

```
$exp = explode(",", $comma_separated);
```

If you require your data to be unique you may include the following:

```
$uniquetags = array_unique($exp, SORT_REGULAR);
```

you can use print_r to see the results of the array resulting

Here array_merge is used because $rt will not get displayed if you are using a 'jquery' autocomplete else $rt may work and array_merge can be ignored. However, you may use array_merge to include multiple tables by repeating the previous process.

```
$autocompletetags = array_merge((array)$uniquetags);
```

This sorts the values in the alphabetic order

```
sort($autocompletetags, SORT_REGULAR);
```