# Making custom full text search on mysql (making index file)

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I'd like to make my own custom full text search and I am not sure what is the best way to make index table.

Ok, I take text field and extract all the words that are longer than 3 to the index table. But what do I have to store about them? word, ID of the table where I am searching? Anything else? Frequency of the word?

And support question: How do I split the text field to words, is there any mysql function or should I do this using server side language?

UPDATE: To make things clear: I don't need full text search just a wordlist of the words that are in all records of my text field, so I could search for the endings with LIKE 'word%'

Comment: Why do you not want to use the build-in full-text-search? See match against:.

Comment: I just need word table... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712729/mysql-extract-specific-words-from-text-field-using-full-text-search

Answer (score 4):

If you are only going to implement what `MySQL` calls `boolean mode` (no relevance counting), you should implement the following basic functionality:

1. A `wordbreaker`, an algorithm that splits the strings into words. This is trivial in English but can be a problem for some Asian languages which do not use spaces between words.
2. Optionally, a `stemmer`, an algorithm which reduces words to their basic forms, so that `went` and `gone` both become `go`.
3. Optionally, a `spellchecker`, an algorithm which corrects the common spelling errors.
4. Optionally, a `thesaurus`, which reduces the synonyms to their common form.

A result of all this is that you have a string like this:

```
a fast oburn vixen jmups over an indolent canine
```

split into the basic forms of the words with the synonyms replaced and errors corrected:

```
quick
brown
fox
jump
over
lazy
dog
```

Then you just create a composite index on `(word, rowid)`, where `word` is the basic form and `rowid` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the record indexed.

To query for, say, `'+quick +fox'`, you should search your index for these words and find an intersection on `rowid`. The intersecting `rowid` will contain both words.

If you are going to take relevance into account, you should additionally maintain a per-word statistics in a separate index over the whole corpus.

I should warn you that this is not a simple task. Just take a look at `Sphinx` source code.

Comment: Thanx, I just need the word list for the word endings, sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. But thank you for a good answer. Stemmer for my language is non existant so no, I don't dare to make a full text mysqlf ;-(

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do it**
Unless you know what you are doing forget about rolling your own full-text-search.
Let MySQL do the heavy lifting.

1. Use MyISAM for the table your want to search on
2. Put a `FULLTEXT` index on the text-fields you want to index.

Then do

```
SELECT *, MATCH(field1, field2) AGAINST 'text to search' 
  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION AS relevancy 
FROM table1 
WHERE MATCH(field1, field2) AGAINST 'text to search' 
  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION
ORDER BY relevancy
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

Comment: Thanx, I don't need a search, I just need to build an words table so I can find word endings (long story). I just want an word table from a text field.

Comment: Aha, I suggest you edit your question to include that fact. It will make it easier to give a good answer to your question.

Comment: If you store your words the other way round, you can use `like 'xxx%' to search for word endings.

Answer (score 0):

OP indicated that he want to search for word endings.

Where I live (Holland) we do poems in December, so I do a lot of word ending searching to find words that ryhme.
Here's my trick.

Add a new field to your table named `visa_versa: varchar indexed`

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytable.visa_versa = REVERSE(mytable.myword);
```

Now you can do an indexed search on word endings with

```
SET @ending = 'end';
SELECT myword FROM mytable where visa_versa LIKE REVERSE(CONCAT('%',@ending));
```

Comment: Hm, but I don't have single word in a varchar, I have a text field with a lot of text in it. I needk to break the text field to get words.